# Number of action per year. Combinatorics question

Tags: math, combinations

I'm writing a diploma about vaccines. There is a region, its population and 12 month. There is an array of 12 values from 0 to 1 with step 0.01. It means which part of population should we vaccinate in every month. 
For example if we have array = [0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]. That means that we should vaccinate 0.1 of region population only in first month. 
Another array = [0, 0.23,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0.02,0,0,0]. It means that we should vaccinate 0.23 of region population in second month and 0.02 of region population in 9th month. 
So the question is: how to generate (using 3 loops) 12(months) * 12(times of vaccinating) * 100 (number of steps from 0 to 1) = 14_400 number of arrays that will contain every version of these combinations.

For now I have this code:

```
for(int month = 0;month<12;month++){
   for (double step = 0;step<=1;step+=0.01){
      double[] arr = new double[12];
      arr[month] = step;
   }
}
```

I need to add 3d loop that will vary number of vaccinating per year.
Have no idea how to write it.

Idk if it is understandable. 
Hope u get it otherwise ask me, please.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, your question is not clear. Is it possible to vaccinate part of the population more than once? In other words, does the sum of the values in the array need to be at most one? Are there any other restrictions on your "combinations"? In just about any meaning of your question that I can see, your formula for the "number of arrays" is wrong. Consider that the number of months must equal the number of "times of vaccinating". Please justify the use of those three loops and of that formula.

Comment: I don't understand what are `12(times of vaccinating)`.The same as `months`? In this case perhaps there are 10^24 variants (if `parts of populations` are independent month from month)

Comment: @RoryDaulton I edited my question. 
1. It is possible to vaccinate population from 1 up to 12 times. If we go with 12 times, it means 1 time per month. 
2. No other restriction.
3. Min number of vaccination  = 1 - 1 time in any of 12 month with step variation from 0 to 1 (0.01 step) => 100 vaccination options for 1 month => varying certain month for vaccination we get 1200 options for vaccination 1 times per year in any month.

Comment: @MBo I have 12 months. So I can vaccinate population min - 1 times (in any of 12 month) up to 12 times (every month).

Comment: What is the last variant - 12 x 1.00 (all population is vaccinated monthly)?

Comment: @MBo yes. first 12 х 0, last 12 x 1.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 101 variants for the first month `0.00, 0.01..1.00`
And 101 variants for the second month - same values. 
And 101*101 possible combinations for two months.

Continuing - for all 12 months you have `101^12 variants ~ 10^24`
It is not possible to generate and store so many combinations (at least in the current decade)

If step is larger than 0.01, then combination count might be reliable. General formula is `P=N^M` where N is number of variants per month, M is number of months

You can traverse all combinations representing all integers in range `0..P-1` in N-ric numeral system. Or make digit counter:

```
 fill array D[12] with zeros
 repeat
    increment element at the last index by step value
    if it reaches the limit, make it zero 
                    and increment element at the next index
 until the first element reaches the limit
```

It is similar to counting 08, 09, here we cannot increment 9, so make 10 and so on

```
s = 1
m = 3
mx = 3
l = [0]*m
i = 0
while i < m:
    print([x/3 for x in l])
    i = 0
    l[i] += s
    while (i < m) and l[i] > mx:
        l[i] = 0
        i += 1
        if i < m:
            l[i] += s
```

Python code prints 64 (`(mx/s+1)^m=4^3`) variants like `[0.3333, 0.6666, 0.0]`

Comment: What if I reduce number of possible vaccination up to 3 for example.

Comment: General formula N^K

Comment: This works totally fine, but I have a question. If I need to limit number of maximum number of vaccines how should I implement it. I mean, if I have 12x0 array and I want to set max number of elements to 2 so center variant will be [5x0, maxNumber, maxNumber, 5x0] and last array will be [10x0, max, max]

Comment: You can just count a number of maxNumber. If limit is reached, perform carry `l[i] > mx:` earlier than mx